# Pandas One by One Entry with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

so I am building a simple app here I wanted some values to be put into my csv via PANDAS
each time there was an entry in the interface. Here's my code:

```
filename = 'sheet2.csv'
pathto_csv = os.path.join('Walenv/',filename)
if request.method == 'POST':
   try:
      data_df = pd.read_csv(pathto_csv, delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig" )
      lookup=request.form['lookup']
      product = wapy.product_lookup(lookup)
      print (product.name)
      i=1
      while(i != 0):
        data_df.set_value([i], ['Walmart SKU'], lookup)
        data_df.set_value([i], ['Price'], product.name)
        data_df.to_csv(pathto_csv)
        i+=1



   except EmptyDataError:
      pass


   path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'Walenv')
   return send_from_directory (path, filename)

else:
   return render_template('success.html')
```

But what this does is that every entry that goes in every column fills up everything,
here's an image:
[image]

[IMG1]

what I wanted to do was to add it one by one. for example

1   14660314    Bowflex Blaze Home Gym
2   42142144    Product Item Number2
3   25235255    Product Item Number3

In this case I had three entries in total. I thought of putting it in a loop so that it would
remember the index, everytime I add something new. How do I fix this so I can get my desired output?

I tried putting it out of the loop and removing the i and yeah, as you can expect it only replaces the
values

Comment: This is terribly inefficient.  Why read the csv file only to rewrite it again.  Can't you just append to the csv (without Pandas)?

Comment: Just to begin with, your `i` is 1 before the `while` loop, and at the end of the loop you are increasing `i` by 1. At the same time doing `while(i != 0)`. Is it ever going to be 0 so it stops? Isn't it always remain nonzero?

Comment: Secondly, don't iterate on index, that is bad. If you have to, don't use `set_value`, it is deprecated. Use `iloc`. But notice: If `lookup` and `product.name` are single values, how can you expect to write different items into different cells of the DataFrame? Can you show us what they look like? Maybe you should collect all  `lookup` and `product.name`s, and then do a one-off assignment like `data_df['Walmart SKU'] = lookup` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this even without pandas, for example:

```
fields=[lookup + ',' + str(product.sale_price) + ',' + instock + ',' + product.stock + ',' + str(product.msrp) + ',' + st + ',' + str(product.msrp)]
with open(r'sheet.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```

Every entry that you have, CSV in order to be distributed to the cells needs comma, all you need is to get all your entries and concatenate them to each other with a comma in between:

```
fields=[lookup + ',' + str(product.sale_price) + ',' + instock + ',' + product.stock + ',' + str(product.msrp) + ',' + st + ',' + str(product.msrp)]
```

and write is in the CSV using the code I provide above. This should solve your problem. Instead of pandas just use the csv import.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1
  while(i != 0):
    data_df.set_value([i], ['Walmart SKU'], lookup)
    data_df.set_value([i], ['Price'], product.name)
    data_df.to_csv(pathto_csv)
    i+=1
```

is incorrect logic, it is an infinite loop and this is causing the same row filling the entire csv.